# No hard feelings against anyone

Tags: riddle, steganography

> When I first saw a puzzle on this site for weeks ago, I thought Hey, this looks like fun. Even today, I still think this is an amazing site. Not only is it fun, it is also educating many times. 
>   What I especially like is people helping each other. I think this is one of the few places on the internet where people are still civil to each other. Let's not forget the encouragement people receive here! Love the inspiring and the inspired puzzles and authors. Really, I sometimes feel like my fellow puzzlers are my pen friends. I know many of you will agree with me.
>
> Lastly I hope and pray this site will remain as amusing as it is now. Even as the number of members increase, it is our responsibility as current members to make sure we show newcomers that we are a principled site for civilized people. Yup, let's toast to that!
>
> Sorry I made you read an essay. Even though it was longer than expected, it was definitely something I've wanted to express for quite some time now. Now then, it's time for me to end this rant. Don't forget that this is a puzzle as well. ;)

Comment: I think you need steganography tag

Comment: In the last paragraph, is the "easy" a typo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay, let's try:

> when I read the first letter of each sentence I see:
>  **When will Rileys end**

and then I realize

> Why the title was like that :)

Comment: That's not partial, that's the full answer :D Was going through the puzzle list and just wanted to make something different :P

Comment: Will accept it in a little while :)

Comment: wow, actually, I really enjoying wondering how people can make a stegano puzzle, and I think this is the first time I solve it :o nice!

Comment: That's great! :D I think I'm yet to solve my first stegano puzzle... Also I'll make a slightly harder one next time. Don't miss it!

Comment: It's not quite rot13(Gur svefg yrggre bs rnpu fragrapr, ohg gur jbeqf jvgu pncvgnyvfngvba (Nygubhtu vg qbrfa'g vapyhqr nyy bs gur fvatyr V bppheeraprf, V guvax bayl gur barf ng gur fgneg.) Either way, I got this answer too, and I'd like to apologise to @nikki because i may be the cause of a lot of them :P

Comment: Haha no need to apologise! As I mentioned in the title, no hard feelings :)